# Getting the value of a child of a unique ID from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to display the user's current location from the Realtime Database, but it's not displaying on the map, the Database is structured like this:

```html
{
  "Blocked Users" : {
    "RCX2HZXIwlSmMHFgDytf1DgZBgi2" : 0
  },
  "User Location" : {
    "RCX2HZXIwlSmMHFgDytf1DgZBgi2" : {
      "latitude" : 37.4035483,
      "longitude" : -122.097715
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "RCX2HZXIwlSmMHFgDytf1DgZBgi2" : {
      "Alert Level" : "High",
      "Emergency Type" : "Natural Disaster",
      "address" : "Lapaz Tarlac",
      "emergencyNum" : "0981232387346",
      "name" : "Rafael Campos",
      "phoneNum" : "0981233445675"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting NPEs when fetching the location from Firebase using this code in onMapReady, how should I fix this?

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location");

        uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                    Double latitude = snapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double longitude = snapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(getCompleteAddress(latitude, longitude)));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,14F));
                    Log.d("TAG", "latitude, longitude");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

This is the stack trace:

```
2021-10-23 11:19:19.139 12376-12376/com.example.rescuealertadmin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rescuealertadmin, PID: 12376
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rescuealertadmin.RetrieveMapsActivity$4.onComplete(RetrieveMapsActivity.java:202)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Hey Rafael. You have accepted an answer which uses a 100% copied solution. That's not how you should deal with such situations.

Comment: Hey Rafael, i might copied a solution but i have answered your comment before anyone has does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the foll9ow error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Because you are using an incorrect reference in your code. As I see, both "latitude" and "longitude" are direct children of the UID. So please change the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location");
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

To:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

The rest of the code may remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your `User Location` path has a list of users, so your `onComplete` needs to handle the fact that the `DataSnapshot` has a list of child nodes too by looping over the results:

```
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Double latitude = child.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                Double longitude = child.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                ...
    }
});
```

Comment: It's still not showing the user's location, just the whole map.

Comment: If the error message disappears, this change solves the problem you posted about. You might still have other problems, but this was definitely one of them - and the one causing the error message. To further troubleshoot, I recommend setting a breakpoint on the first line in `onComplete` and stepping through the code to see what values you get.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding data on the wrong node.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

Here you have saved Users Information

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location");
```

And then you're going into "Users" Node Further. But there is NO "User Location" In "Users" Node.

You can get data like this if you have UID

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User Location").child(UID);
```

Comment: I've already fixed the references and the map is still not displaying the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing wrong ref path that's why you are getting NPE.

Convert it from:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location");
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

to

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User Location").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(//);
```

Comment: I've already fixed the references and the map is still not displaying the user's location.

Comment: what you are getting in response?

Comment: I tried removing the '.child(uid)' in the reference, and the marker appears but it's says in the logcat 'No setter/field for <UID> found on class com.example.rescuealertadmin.LocationSend (which is my class)

Comment: just print whole snap shot in logcat in show what you are getting.

Comment: I'm finally getting the result that I wanted, I ditched the whole referencing the latitudes and longitudes and just put this inside the for loop: "LocationSend send = ds.getValue(LocationSend.class);"